# Shared resource in RIA giving problem

Tags: silverlight

i am using Silverlight business application template, as soon as i change the default namespace of silverligth application, shared resource start giving problem.
While accessing the resource on client side i am getting this error:
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "BusinessApplication1.Web.Resources.ValidationErrorResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "BusinessApplication1" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

While reflector showing resource embedded as BusinessApplication1.Client.Assets.Resources.ErrorResources.resources

I tried to generate designer file for client seperatly in that case Ria Client Code generation comments shared resource Attributes.

Any idea!!!

Comment: Have you updated your service reference?